# Cannot get grunt preprocess to replace value

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I want to use [grunt preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess/).

In **app/index.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var configValue = '/* @echo FOO */' || 'default value';
        console.log('A');
        console.log(configValue);
        console.log('B');
</script>
```

My gruntfile:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  ...
  grunt.initConfig({
    ...
    preprocess: {
      options: {
        context : {
          DEBUG: true,
          FOO: 'bar'
        }
      },
      multifile : {
        files : {
          'app/index.processed.html' : 'app/index.html'
          //,'test/test.processed.js'   : 'test/test.js'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');

  ...
};
```

Then I use the command:

```
% grunt preprocess
Running "preprocess:multifile" (preprocess) task

Done, without errors.

Elapsed time
preprocess:multifile  22ms
Total                 22ms
```

It generates the file app/index.processed.html, but this file still has the line:

`var configValue = '/* @echo FOO */' || 'default value';`

The value has not been replaced. What am I missing ?

---

**Edit:**

I have tried to see what happens to a block like this:

```
<!-- @ifdef DEBUG -->
  <h1>Test Page</h1>
<!-- @endif -->

<!-- @exclude -->
<header>You're on dev!</header>
<!-- @endexclude -->
```

And it is replaced with: `<h1>Test Page</h1>` (keeping the same context options as before).

So it looks like the preprocessing is happening. The preprocess task is just not recognising `'/* @echo FOO */'` as something to be replaced. Which is wierd, because I took it from the [sample on github](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess/#what-does-it-look-like).

**Edit2:**

`<p><!-- @echo FOO --></p>` is replaced with `<p>bar</p>`, which is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that your example is inside a html tag and the other one is probably inside a .js file.

#### preprocess uses differnt syntax for html and js ( and coffee)

- https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess/blob/master/lib/regexrules.js

#### use this syntax inside html tags:

```
 var configValue = '<!-- @echo FOO -->' || 'default value';
```

#### here is an example:

- https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess#extended-html-syntax

Comment: The preprocessing does work, but my IDE doesn't like syntax '<!-- @echo FOO -->', it says: unclosed string literal.

Comment: IDEs are lame, why the hack they care about what's inside a string literal.

Comment: I ended up making a config.js file, where `// @echo FOO` works.